# Global logger variable for dll

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I'm working on a C# project in Visual Studio. The project compiles to a DLL, which contains a series of classes, and I'm using Nlog for logging. I'm familiar with setting up the `NLog.config` to have my targets and rules all set up. I have the `NLog.config` file set to copy to output directory on compile. The DLL is a plugin for a main application. Once the main application is launched it reads an `.addin` file pointing it to the DLL and the functionality that I wrote becomes available in the main application. I don't have access to the code base for the main application, that is out of my hands.

In my project I have a static property that calls [Nlog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetCurrentClassLogger.htm). This line of code is in every class.

```
 public static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

The `_logger` variable is accessible in each class. Copying the same line of code in each class doesn't feel right. I'm curious if there is a more efficient way to create a logger variable at a global level within the DLL project so that I only have to create the static variable once in the entire project.

Comment: The idea with creating a logger inside each class, is that the output coming from the different classes can be distinguished based on the logger-name [${logger}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer). You are free to just having a global Logger-instance used by all classes. Notice that if the host-application or other other plugins that also depend on NLog and each bring their own NLog.config, then consider an isolated LogFactory-instance - https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging#isolated-logfactory

Comment: Thank you @RolfKristensen for the note and for the link. This is extremely helpful.